# DataFileSync flushing mmaps takes a long time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, database, mongodb

We are running MongoDB 2.6.9 on a 64 bit Ubuntu Linux VM. When I look in the database folder, this is what I see with ls -lh:

```
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb  64M Apr 15 14:26 admin.0
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb  16M Apr 15 14:26 admin.ns
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup  64M Jun 17 11:56 my_database.0
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 128M May  7 23:15 my_database.1
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 256M Jun 15 07:40 my_database.2
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 512M May 14 07:26 my_database.3
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 1.0G Jun 10 09:26 my_database.4
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2.0G Jun  2 11:25 my_database.5
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2.0G Jun 17 12:03 my_database.6
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2.0G Jun 17 12:03 my_database.7
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 2.0G Jun 17 12:03 my_database.8
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup  16M Jun 17 12:03 my_database.ns
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Jun 16 13:16 journal
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb  64M Jun 16 13:16 local.0
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb  16M Jun 16 13:16 local.ns
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mongodb mongodb    5 Jun 16 13:16 mongod.lock
```

So we have a few 2GB files. But the problem is that periodically we get a log message like this:

```
2015-06-12T18:10:01.790-0700 [DataFileSync] flushing mmaps took 62192ms  for 14 files
```

During this period of time mongodb locks up and all queries fail.

How do we fix this issue?

Comment: What values are you seeing for IOwait during this period?

Comment: How would I check the values for IOWait?

Comment: iostat says iowait times are 0.09%. Doesn't look significant to me.

Comment: that's when the mmap flush is happening?

Comment: No that's now. I never know when mmap is being flushed. The logs report long mmap flushing times many hours apart. So the server will run fine for several hours, then all of sudden the mmap flush kicks in and evrything grinds to a halt.

Comment: The important iowait figure is during a flush. Install sysstat and configure it to collect information frequently. Hopefully it'll catch one of these episodes.

Comment: Can you tell me what to look for? If I see a large IOWait what do I do?

Comment: You get faster disks or find some other way to prevent mongo from doing this.